# Change a sentence color in UIWebview on single tap

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am displaying a large text in a `UIWebView`. What I want to do is when the user taps anywhere the whole sentence should be highlight, or you can say I can get the range of the sentence and I can change color of the same. I have not written any code for this but I am not able to apply proper logic as well.

Any help. Thanks.

**Update**

What I am doing is that I am loading a long text NSString using html. The string contains more than one sentence. Now what my requirement is that when I tap on a word it should highlight (for example, change the text color) for the whole sentence. I tried to write a javascript for it(which I got from somewhere on the internet) and called the getSelection method, but nothing happened.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S.-I don't know javascript. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. All i did was make a css file, and I inserted all the sentences under and  tag, then changed the color of  tag on `hover` to the desired color.

Code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type='text/css'>
            a:link {
                text-decoration : none;
                color: black;
            }

        a:visited {
            color: black;
        }

        a:hover {
            color: red;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a>My Text</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight the texts in a UIWebView using simple javascript function.
Try the below tutorial

[Highlighting Text in a UIWebView](http://brainwashinc.com/2010/02/10/highlighting-text-in-a-uiwebview/)

Comment: Linked answers should include the basics of the solution from the link so they're still useful if the link breaks.

Comment: I tried this link and various other links. But nothing actually does the work. Not even close. May be if I am able to change certain js code I will be able to achieve what i want but the problem is I have absolute NO knowledge of javascript, which is making my task even more difficult. I tried to achieve this by loading the data in a UITextView but still too far from the requirement. :(